# How do I convert a 5-tuple NFA to a diagram?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

The only information I have is a nondeterministic finite automaton $(K, \Sigma, \Delta, s, F)$ where:

$$K = {p, q, r}\  \Sigma = {a, b, c}\ s = p\ F = {q}\ \Delta = {(p, a, q), (q, b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read it off directly from $\Delta$. You have three states, $p$, $q$, and $r$. $\Delta$ shows that there are just four transitions: $p\overset{a}\longrightarrow q$, $q\overset{a}\longrightarrow p$, $q\overset{b}\longrightarrow r$, and $r\overset{c}\longrightarrow q$. The initial state is $p$, and the only acceptor (or final) state is $q$. Just draw your three states, mark the initial and acceptor states, and draw in the four transition arrows.

And this is actually a DFA, so it should be very easy to work with.

Comment: Thank you so much! So would the regex consist of the alphabets a, b, and c? From my understanding p, q, and r are just represent the states? Could I just pretend they're q0, q1, q2?

Comment: @saralewis: Yes, the input alphabet is $\Sigma=\{a,b,c\}$, and yes, you can rename the states if you like.

Comment: Would you mind checking my DFA diagram for this? https://imgur.com/a/OUR90Q7

Comment: @saralewis: I take it that you’ve renamed $p$ to $q_0$, $q$ to $q_2$, and $r$ to $q_1$; that matches your choice of initial and acceptor states. That means that you should have an $a$-transition from $q_2$ to $q_0$ as well as the one from $q_0$ to $q_2$: the triple $(q,a,p)$ in $\Delta$ would be $(q_2,a,q_0)$ with your state labels. Your $c$-transition from $q_1$ to $q_2$ is correct, matching $(r,c,q)$ in $\Delta$, but your two loops are clearly wrong: $\Delta$ contains no loops. Also, $\Delta$ contains only $4$ transitions, not $5$. You should have a $b$-transition from $q_2$ to $q_1$.

Comment: Oops, I think I interpreted q2 ->q0 as a loop for some reason. I've fixed it, does this look correct now? https://imgur.com/a/5XliAJ3

Comment: @saralewis: Almost: your $b$-transition is misplaced. It should go from $q$ to $r$, i.e, from $q_2$ to $q_1$.

Comment: oh whoops. thank you for your help!!

Comment: @saralewis: You’re welcome!

Comment: Follow up question - I'm struggling with converting this to Regex. I tried to do it sorta algebraically but miserably failed so I'm guessing + checking - so far I have something like `a(a^+)(bc)`. I want a, then at least one or more a's, and if there are at least one or more a's (following the first a), then there will be one (bc). How can I fix what I have so far to depict that?

Comment: @saralewis: $aa^+$ won’t quite work: you need to start with an odd number of $a$s, so you want to start with $(aa)^*a$. After that you can have any number of repetitions of $bc$; that gives you $(aa)^*a(bc)^*$. Finally, that whole thing can be repeated any number of times, so you end up with $\left((aa)^*a(bc)^*\right)^*$.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you!

Comment: @saralewis: You’re welcome!